# detect drag&Drop invocation in a windows script and cancel main operation

Tags: windows, cmd, scripting, imagemagick

I have a script file centercrop50.bat that does mainly a crop on all jpg-images in a folder:

```
for %%i in (*.jpg) do convert %%i -gravity Center -crop 50%%x+0+0  cc50_%%i
```

convert is a CLI-command I installed with imagemagick.

Actually I select a few files to be processed from a large pic-directory, copy them to a workbench folder with this script, then I want to start the script on those files in the workbench directory.

Now I learned while testing an using, that this script also fires, when I accidently drop the files directly to the script, instead to the directory. The difference depends of the dropzone of the files and may be subtle.

Unexpectatly in this case all the foto is the sourcefolder of the drag operaterion are going to be processed by the for-loop.

This means the script will work on my original picture library [sic!, omg!!]
This is far to much of risk to me and it is not what I intent the script to do.

Thus I need some envelope coding to detect if the script is tempted to work on files outside the script's sourcepath and skip the crop alltogether in that case.

I found out that the sourcepath of the script can be evaluated with %~dp0, but then I'm a bit stuck, as I'm not very seasoned in CMD-scripting.

Can you offer help?

Comment: You could process all the images in a folder in ImageMagick using mogrify rather than a script loop. Don't know if that will help you. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Comment: What is the `%%x` part in `-crop 50%%x+0+0`? another `for` variable reference?

Comment: Drag-and-drop executes the script probably with `C:\Windows\System32` or similar as the working directory. Yes, `%~dp0` points to the directory containing the script. Hence use `for %%i in ("%~dp0*.jpg") do convert "%%~i" ... "%%~dpicc50_%%~nxi"` (assuming the last part specifies the new name of the output file)...

Comment: Apart from the solution of Quickfix, this seems to be an elegant alternative. Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is detect if your script has been called with parameters or directly.

In cmd, the parameters passed to the script are called %1 %2 ... or you have %* that contains all the parameters.

Here is a script that does nothing if it is called with parameters :

```
@echo off
if not "%*"=="" goto errorparams
for %%i in (*.png) do convert %%i -gravity Center -crop 50%%x+0+0  cc50_%%i
goto end
:errorparams
echo script must be launched directly
:end
pause
```

Comment: Thanks, this is elegant. Thats what I was looking for.